# DataTable breaks Nested Repeater and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, nested-repeater

I've run into a issue with DataTables and Nested Repeaters. It basically says that I haven't gotten the correct matching tr td tags.

Yet, I've followed the Nested Repeater tutorial from the link below and to me that the HTML is formed correctly and when I check the DOM and everything seems to be fine. The table looks like a normal table, which then confuses my as top why it's breaking when I initialize the Datatble.

[Click here to see the Nested Repearter Tutorial Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Nested-Repeater-Repeater-inside-Repeater-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx).

It looks  However, when I initialize the DataTable (#TeamDashboard) I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined


jquery.dataTables.min.js?v=6754017259857097728:24
```

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTeamPlayers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTeamPlayers_ItemDataBound">               
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="TeamDashboard" class="table table-striped table-condensed marginBottom30 resultTeams" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 setColumnPlusMinus"></th>
                    <th class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Name</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">Status</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></th>
                    <th class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Positions</th>
                    <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"></th>
                    <th class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="searchable">                                                           
    </HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr role="row" class="odd shown regularRow">

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPlayerDetails" runat="server" >
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptPlayerDetails" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<table  cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table noPad selected2 closeMe">--%>
                        <tr class="table noPad selected2 closeMe newRow">
                            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 padLeft"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> | <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventDate") %></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventType") %></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EventName") %> <i class="fa fa-check-circle colorGreen"></i></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col2"></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                <!-- Split button -->
                                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-xs-9 col-md-10">Player Dashboard</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle col-xs-3 col-md-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
                                        <li class="NewEvent"><a href="#">New Event</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <%--</table>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </asp:Panel>  
            <td class="details-control">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>                                                                        
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPlayerId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlayerId") %>' />
            </td>

            <td class="sorting_1">
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlayerName") %></td>
            <td>
<div class='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status").ToString().Equals("Able")?"well green status":"well red status" %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %></div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Position") %> </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Split button -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="DIR btn btn-sm btn-default col-md-8"><a data-toggle="modal" href="ModalWindows/Daily_Injury_Report.aspx" data-target="#Daily_Injury_Report" class="openDIR">Open DIR</a></button>
                    <div type="button" class="DIR openDIR_icon btn-sm btn-default col-md-4 dropdown-toggle" >
                    <div class="text-center centerGlyphicon"><i class="fa fa-check-circle colorGreenTop" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Split button -->
                <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-xs-9 col-md-10">Player Dashboard</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle col-xs-3 col-md-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="NewEvent"><a href="#">New Event</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>       
        </tr>   


</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is the code for the initializing the DataTable:

```
var table = $('#TeamDashboard').DataTable({
"retrieve": true,
"bStateSave": true,
select: true,
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
oLanguage: {
    sLengthMenu: "_MENU_",
},
"bAutoWidth": true,
"searching": false,
bFilter: true, // This Turns Off The Search Box
bInfo: true,
"order": [[2, "desc"]],
"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">', 
"aoColumnDefs": [{ aTargets: [0], bSortable: false },
{ aTargets: [3], bSortable: false },
{ aTargets: [3], bSearchable: false },
{ aTargets: [2], bSearchable: false },
{ aTargets: [5], bSortable: false },
{ aTargets: [5], bSearchable: false,
{ aTargets: [5], bSearchable: false }]
});
```

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong? Everything seems to be fine, except it end up breaking my JS.

It looks to me as soon as I initialize the DataTable it then breaks the JS on the page...

Thanks in Advance 
BMCC

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The mismatch in the number of header columns cause this issue, there should be equal number of header columns and the row columns.
Or the mismatch "aoColumns" or "aoColumnDefs"

Comment: My problem was a mismatch in the number of `<td> </td>` when I presented the default table without data. I was just rendering 1 `<td>` and the message for the "empty state". As soon as I matched the same number of `<td>` with the  number of `<th>` I got rid of the problem.

Comment: So how can I draw a cell with colspan without having this issue?

Comment: In my application that header column not same then , how can I solve this issue

Comment: @PauloMadroñero  Just check your list size before call the .datatable(). e.g:

                if ([[${!objects?.isEmpty()}]]) {
                    $('#datatable').DataTable();
                }

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with the wrong index in the columnDefs:

```
"columnDefs": [
        {  // set default column settings
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": [1, 2, 4]
        }
]
```

Note that the `targets` specify the column index which start at 0. In my case I did not have a 5th column but I mentioned `4` index which was giving me the error.

Answer (score 2):

Check the number of columns set...

```
"aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    { "sType": "uk_date" },
    { "sType": "uk_date" },
    null,
    null
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue and the solve is : 
you must send the data inside the table in tbody tag without let any column empty that u write in the thead tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that there are no extra tags opened. This error shows up when there is a tag mismatch, for example `<th><tr>` or `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so i used display property of CSS.

```html
@if( Str::startsWith($value, 'image/') )
<td style="display: none" ></td>
<td style="display: none"></td>
@else
    <td>{!! ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)) !!}</td> 
    <td>
        @if($value == '0')
        No
        @elseif($value == '1')
        Yes
        @else
        {{ $value }}
        @endif
    </td>   
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this error when I called Datatable methods and I had 2 tables on the same page with the same id.  So something like:

```
<table id="myTable"/> 
... 
<table id="myTable"/>
```